# jQuery radio button unchecked error

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying a form validation using jQuery, I found some error which I can't understand.

I'm having two radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id = "gender"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id = "gender"/>Female
```

And validating if these are checked

```
if(! $('#gender').attr('checked')){
                alert('Please select your gender');
                return false;
            }
```

The problem is when I check the first radio button and submit the form, I dont get the alert, but when I check the second radio button(Female) and submit the form , I get the alert as "Please select your gender".

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

First, as j08691 mentioned in a comment, no two HTML elements can have the same `id` attribute. Second, `checked` functions as a property, not an attribute. Use `$("#gender").prop("checked")` instead; this will return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
if(!$('[name="gender"]:checked').size())
     alert('Please select your gender');
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/cbsLq59t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var isChecked = $('[name="gender"]:checked').length;

if(isChecked < 1) {
    alert("please Select your gender");
}
```

## [JSFiddile](http://jsfiddle.net/hwnj4mh5/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's ID detection simply matches the first instance of an ID and doesn't bother to continue searching as the `id` attribute is intended to be **unique**.

To fix your issue, firstly remove those duplicated ID attributes and change your jQuery selector from:

```
$('#gender')
```

To:

```
$('[name="gender"]')
```

You can then combine this with jQuery's `:checked` selector as well to determine whether one of the `radio` elements is checked:

```
if ( $('[name="gender"]:checked').length === 1 ) {
    alert('Please select your gender');
    return false;
}
```