# Jquery function that checks every form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have been working on this for 3 days, and still cannot get it to work.

I want a function that checks every form field, and will alert if not filled.
But also a unique alert message for every field. For example : "field 1 is not filled", "field 2 is not filled", etc...

I have tried 2 functions. This one:

```
function tashlum() {
    if (emptyElements.length === 0) {
        alert("הכל מלא")
    } else {
        alert("לא מלא")
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
function tashlum() {  
    var x = document.forms["fr1"]["company"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("אנא מלא את שם החברה בטופס")
        var y = document.forms["fr1"]["mem"].value;
        if (y == null || y == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר בסוג הזכרון בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var y = document.forms["fr1"]["mem"].value;
        if (y == null || y == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר בסוג הזכרון בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.forms["fr1"]["select0"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר באופצית הזכרון בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.forms["fr1"]["screen"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר את גודל המסך בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.forms["fr1"]["camera"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר את סוג המצלמה בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.forms["fr1"]["bat"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר את סוג הבטריה בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.forms["fr1"]["ez"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("אנא בחר את אזור הרכישה בטופס")
            return false;
        }
        else {
            window.open("tashlum.html");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="fr1" action="http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/cgi-bin/mycgi.pl " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return tashlum()">
```

Comment: Please  format your code properly ;__;

Comment: Your code is wrong formatted and  you forgot a curly bracket at end of the second function, you html is really incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="" />
    ...
    <input type="text" name="field99" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you can loop through the input elements like this:

```
var textFields = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 input[type=text]");

for(var i=0; i<textFields.length; i++){
  //Test the value here...
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function validateForm(){
    var textFields = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 input[type=text]");
    
    for(var i=0; i<textFields.length; i++){
        if(textFields[i].value == ''){
            alert(textFields[i].name + ' is not filled');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="First Name" value="" /></label><br />
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" value="" /></label><br />
    <label>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="Phone Number" value="" /></label><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it work with Radio buttons?\Select(options) \ checkbox? i have all of them

Answer (score 0):

Here is the soultion according to the answers here and another topic :[jQuery radio button unchecked error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288484/jquery-radio-button-unchecked-error). 
First code for normal input (text) + Including other input( 2 radio fields)

```
        function tashlum() { 
        var textFields = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 input");

        for (var i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
            if (textFields[i].value == '') {
                alert( 'אנא מלא את ה' + textFields[i].id);
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($('[name="camera"]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('אנא בחר את סוג המצלמה');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('[name="memory"]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('אנא בחר את סוג הזכרון');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks mate for helping me. see you in next question.